# How to check expiration date of apple receipt?

Tags: javascript, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo, react-native-ios

am working with in app purchase in react-native.am using expo-in-app-purchase.in order to validate receipt with app store am getting something like this:

```
 result [
 {
      .........................
       purchase_date: '2021-05-03 11:34:17 Etc/GMT',
        purchase_date_ms: '1620041657000',
      purchase_date_pst: '2021-05-03 04:34:17 America/Los_Angeles',
     original_purchase_date: '2021-05-03 11:33:20 Etc/GMT',
      original_purchase_date_ms: '1620041600000',
       original_purchase_date_pst: '2021-05-03 04:33:20 America/Los_Angeles',
        expires_date: '2021-05-03 11:39:17 Etc/GMT',
      expires_date_ms: '1620041957000',
       expires_date_pst: '2021-05-03 04:39:17 America/Los_Angeles',
        ...............................................
     }
     ]

 pending_renewal_info:[{
           expiration_intent: '1',
          auto_renew_product_id: '******************',
         is_in_billing_retry_period: '0',
          product_id: '****************************',
        original_transaction_id: '1000000785803993',
         auto_renew_status: '0'
 }]
```

then am trying to check the expiry of subscription Like this:

```
  const expirationDate = result.data.latest_receipt_info[0].expires_date_ms,
        expiry=Date.now() > expirationDate;//it is always true.
```

The expiry getting always true, because the date which apple give is 5 hours before my date.ie, if i purchase something in 2021-05-04 10:00:00 this date, in apple receipt the expiry date is showing something like this 2021-05-04 5:00:00.ie 5 hours behind.then how do i check my receipt expiry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work

```
const expirationDate = parseInt(result.data.latest_receipt_info[0].expires_date_ms);
// Need to parse it to Int as it is in string format originally
const expirationDateObject = new Date(expirationDate);

const current = Date.now();
const currentDateObj = new Date(current);

const isExpired = currentDateObj.getTime() > expirationDateObject.getTime()

console.log(isExpired);
```

Comment: expirationDateObject and currentDateObj is getting invalid date.

Comment: added Edit that string was not being parsed

Comment: If this array works the same way the verifyReceipt works, you shouldn't trust its order. You should always sort this array by `purchase_date_ms ` and get the last entry.

Comment: @romainsalles that array contain only one item

Comment: Oh yes of course, I'm confounding with the "in_app" property. Be careful though, if the client subscribes to 2 products (in 2 different subscription-groups), you'll have 2 entries in this array.

Comment: @KartikeyVaish i have agin problem with this ,ie, expires_date_ms is always behind than date.now.isExpired always getting true.what should i do?

Comment: @romainsalles oh ok, thank you for that information.

Comment: And in fact, `latest_receipt_info` can have multiple entries for a same subscription in S2S notifications (I've just checked in my production data).

Comment: @romainsalles oh ok.Do you have this issue? how do you check the expiration?

Comment: I noticed that your `expires_date_pst` is in `America/Los_Angeles` format..so is it confirmed that it will always give you `expires_date_ms` time stamp from `America/Los_Angeles`??

Comment: When I check the receipt on the server side, I always have a future `expires_date_ms` (unless the receipt is "expired", and in that case it will be in the past). So no, I don't think I have your issue.

Comment: And another thing you have to know: it's not because your receipt has an "expires_date_ms" in the past that you should remove access from your services: it's possible your user is in "grace period" (and in this case, you'll have a past expires_date + a future "grace_period_expires_date_ms" in the "pending_renewal_info" array). More on this here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/is_in_billing_retry_period ("Implement a grace period to improve recovery, if the value is “1” and the expires_date is in the past")

Comment: I agree with @romainsalles

Comment: @romainsalles  ,i added an edit to my question that is pending_renewal_info:[{}].It contain only that much data.And how should i implement geace period?am really stuck on this.

Comment: That's a whole new question and everything is in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/subscriptions_and_offers/reducing_involuntary_subscriber_churn. I suggest you read it: you'll learn a lot of things.